# how to interpolate date for specific number of values in r?

Tags: r, interpolation

This is my data:

```
data<-c(10, 20, 55, 80, 73, 58, 46, 36, 27.5, 20, 15, 13, 11)
```

As it is seen, number of values is 13. But I want it to be 289 values. To perform this, I want to interpolate my data like:

```
10.0 10.2 10.3 10.5 ... 20.0 20.4.. 21.0...55....80...
```

Briefly, I want to assign values between the values of data. The range between two value is not important. But the important thing is, the number of values will be 289. Sorry for my bad narrative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little easier answer:

```
data <- c(10, 20, 55, 80, 73, 58, 46, 36, 27.5, 20, 15, 13, 11)
maxlength <- 315
interpolated_data <- vector()

for (i in 1:(length(data)-1)) {
     interpolated_data <- c(interpolated_data, seq(data[i], data[i+1], length=as.integer((maxlength)/(length(data)-1)))) 
}

while (length(interpolated_data)<maxlength) {
     interpolated_data <- c(interpolated_data, interpolated_data[length(interpolated_data)])
}
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle the case for additional elements that can't be evenly spaced into the intervals. You can use the `while` loop to sort out that behavior. For now I simply added the last element again, but it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly how you want to interpolate between the different values. But the easiest solution is if you simply want values spaced between the minimum and maximum value of the original 13 values to use seq:

```
data <- seq(min(data), max(data), length=289)
```

Of course if you mean that you want to add 289 values the line should be:

```
data <- seq(min(data), max(data), length=289+length(data))
```

Comment: Actually your way is appropriate for me. But it must continue like: 10.0 10.2 10.3 10.5 ... 20.0 20.4.. 21.0...55....80-79.5 79.3....73.....58....52...50...46......27.5.....20....15...13....11.4-11.2-11

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you are trying to achieve without getting more information. Maybe break down your problem into a much smaller toy problem that gives the exact desired output from a specific input?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the clearest explanation for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a little iffy on the in-between sortedness of the numbers, but it does fill in values.

```
datavector <- c(10, 20, 55, 80, 73, 58, 46, 36, 27.5, 20, 15, 13, 11)
desired_length <- 289

make_longer <- function(datavector, desired_length, seed = 4){ 
  
  # floor should ensure you either reach or meet the desired length but 
  # never exceed it 
  multiple <- floor(desired_length/length(datavector))
  set.seed(seed)
  
  holder = NULL
  for(i in 1: (length(datavector)-1) ){ 
    
  min = min( c(datavector[i], datavector[i+1]) )
  max = max( c(datavector[i], datavector[i+1]) )
  
  holder = c(holder, datavector[i],  
             sort ( runif(n = multiple, min = min, max = max ) ) ,
  datavector[i+1])
  }
  
  if(length(holder) < desired_length){ 
    fill_count = desired_length - length(holder)
    
    # store various final values 
    temp_holder = holder[-length(holder)]
    new_min = min( c(holder[length(holder)-1],holder[length(holder)]) )
    new_max = max( c(holder[length(holder)-1],holder[length(holder)]) )
    
    final_holder <- c(temp_holder, sort(
      runif(n = fill_count, min = new_min, max = new_max)
    ) , holder[length(holder)])
    
    return(final_holder)
  } else { 
    return(holder)  
    }

  }
```

[Plot of result for your numbers and seed = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYMVH.png)

Comment: this was helpful but after the peak point, values are sorted increasingly. When we go from 80 to 73, ıt should start with the biggest value. I adjusted the results via excel